# After upgrading my CPU cpufrequtils does not work

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, cpu, cpufreq, governor

After upgrading my CPU (nothing else changed on my system) I can't change the governor of my CPU. I tried reinstalling `cpufrequtils`, but got the following error:

```
Setting up cpufrequtils (008-1) ...

 * Loading cpufreq kernel modules...              [fail] 
 * CPUFreq Utilities: Setting ondemand CPUFreq      
 * disabled, governor not available...             [ OK ]
```

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 on an Intel X5470 (with socket 771 to 775 adapter). I want to use this setup for audio recording, so having the performance governor is essential.

Comment: I get the same problem on Linux Mint and my pc won't shutdown - instead it hangs-up with CPU fan crazy speed - I suspect it's related with cpufrequtils loading problem.